# How can I use a single model struct for data from multiple APIs/sources in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, rest, model

Let's say I want to get news articles from Site A and Site B, each with a different URL and differently structured JSON payloads. Instead of having two different models to manage, I want to combine them into a single "Articles" data model that takes in data from each of the APIs. I'm wanting to know if this possible using CodingKeys or a dictionary or something.

I want to do something like:

```
struct Article: Codable, Hashable {
    var title: String
    var site: String
    var date: String
    var image: String
    var url: String
}
```

and then have CodingKeys to convert the JSON from each site into the shared model. Something like:

```
extension Article {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        var title = "title"
        var site = "site_name"
        var date = "date_published"
        var image = "featured_image_url"
        var url = "article_url"
}
```

But the problem with the above code is that each JSON is different, with different names for the objects. So, then I want to do something like:

```
enum DataSource {
    case siteA
    case siteB
}

extension Article {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        switch DataSource {
        case siteA:
            var title = "title"
            var site = "site_name"
            var date = "date_published"
            var image = "featured_image_url"
            var url = "article_url"
        case siteB:
            var title = "article_title"
            var site = "site_name_long"
            var date = "published_date"
            var image = "featured_image"
            var url = "url"
}
```

and then of course do all the JSONdecoder stuff below that. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass parameter into `decoder` using [`userInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/2892930-userinfo). You can control the way of decoding whatever the way you want by setting extra parameter via `userInfo`. Here i'm passing `Article.Site.a/b` on `site` key.

#### Model definition:

```
// Model
struct Article: Codable, Hashable {
    
    var title: String
    var site: String
    var date: String
    var image: String
    var url: String

    enum Site {
        case a
        case b
    }
    enum SiteError : Error {
        case unknownSite
    }
    enum SiteACodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case site
        case date
        case image
        case url
    }
    enum SiteBCodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case title = "article_title"
        case site = "article_site"
        case date = "article_date"
        case image = "article_image"
        case url = "article_url"
    }


    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        guard   let key = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "site"),
                let value = decoder.userInfo[key],
                let site =  value as? Site else {
            throw SiteError.unknownSite
        }

        switch site {
        case .a:
            let container = decoder.container(keyedBy: SiteACodingKeys)
            
            title = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
            // decode other properties
            
        case .b:
            let container = decoder.container(keyedBy: SiteBCodingKeys)
            
            title = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
            // decode other properties
        }
    }
}
```

#### Decoding:

```
// Decoding
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "site")] = Article.Site.a // Set `Article.Site.b` while data is from site B
// Now use this decoder to decode JSON
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, thanks! I'll get to work on implementing it.